# controls inside div should not be clickable

Tags: html, css

I have question and answers inside div.It contains label for showing question and radiobuttonlist for options .I want user should not be able to copy anything inside this div and radiobuttonlist should not be clickable .I used following css but its not working in IE11.Its working only for input controls .
Please help.

```
#divmain
{  
 pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you question, you would like to prevent users to copy your contenr. You can resovle that by using just CSS user-select like so:

`-moz-user-select: none;

-webkit-user-select: none;

-ms-user-select: none;

-o-user-select: none;

user-select: none;`

This works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, IE10 and up, but not in Opera.

This simply stops a user selecting the text, but that will prevent them copying it. It's nice for text on buttons as well.

In older IE and Opera, you can set it to be unselectable either by using:

`var elem = document.getElementById("yourElement");
elem.unselectable = "on"; // For IE and Opera`

in JS, or simply adding the unselectable attribute and setting it to on.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/B9yYt/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this property is not supported by Opera Mini and IE 11 and below (inclusive). Another solution is needed for these browsers.

jQuery METHOD If you want to disable it via script and not CSS property, these can help you out: If you're using jQuery versions 1.4.3+:

`$('selector').click(false);` 
if not : 
`$('selector').click(function(){return false;});`